# Submit data as JSON with jQuery .ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Ive been on this for several days now and just can't get it right. Im trying to submit a forms data as JSON to a webservice. I have tried both explicitly setting the key value pairs such as

```
data : JSON.stringify({
            type: $('#type').val(),
            country: $('#country').val(),
            identification: $('#identification').val(),
            requtest: $('#request').val(),
            date_of_birth: $('#date_of_birth').val(),
            first: $('#first').val(),
            middle: $('#middle').val(),
            last: $('#last').val(),
            street1: $('#street1').val(),
            street2: $('#street2').val(),
            city: $('#city').val(),
            state: $('#state').val(),
            postal_code: $('postal_code').val(),
            country_code: $('#country_code').val()
          }),
```

and using a function to stringify the data with no results

```
function ConvertFormToJSON(form) {
    var elems = [].slice.call(form.elements);
    var o = {};
    $.each(elems, function() {
        var $this = $(this), g = $this.data('group');
        if (g) {
            if ( !o.hasOwnProperty(g) ) o[g] = {};
            o[g][this.name] = this.value;
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value;
        }
        });

    return o;
    }
submitHandler: function(form) {
      var form = this;
      var json = ConvertFormToJSON(form.currentForm);
      console.log('Here is the json' + json);
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'webserviceURL',
        crossDomain:true,
        data: json,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( data ){
          alert(data);
        },
        error: function ( xhr, errorType, exception ) {
          var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText;
          $('#USForm').fadeOut('fast');
          $('#formContain').html('<p>We are sorry, but the following error has occurred:<br />' + errorMessage +'</p>');
        }  
      })
      .always(function(){
        console.log("always:" + json);
      })
      .done(function (response){
        console.log("done:" + json);
      })
      .fail(function(){
       console.log("fail" + json);
      });
      return false;
  },
//rest of validation stuff
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3J57y/)

Comment: ...but what's the problem you're having? Your jsFiddle has a few different issues. Your form default submit action is firing before your click handler, and doing a redirect. If you kill that you get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined` because you reference `form.currentForm` without defining it.

Comment: `ConvertFormToJSON` returns an object, not JSON -- it needs to do `return JSON.stringify(o)`.

Comment: What is the webserverice? It may need you to give a parameter name to the JSON, e.g. `data: { json: json }`.

Comment: As you both can see, I don't have a very good grasp on JSON. Barmar, yes the json has some nested child/grandchild formatting. When I console.log the json, it is as it needs to be formatted. I keep getting errors in the console stating that 'cannot read elements of undefined' and the returned error is [
"JsonError"
]

Comment: Yep, it seems like the issue may be on the ASP side. This is its response to a valid request (based on given info): `["JsonError"]{"d":null}`

Comment: What is a better way of submitting JSON, nothing I've found works for me.

Comment: The problem doesn't really seem to be with submitting the JSON. Are you also maintaining the back-end service? You need to ensure that the data your sending is compliant with their specification. You have to match the format they're expecting so they can parse it.

Comment: No, I am not maintaining the back end. I just need to be sure the JSON is being submitted correctly. Back End Guy used an example with one hardcoded value, data: "{'request':'foovalue'}",and says his end is good to go

Comment: Ok well you may need to go back to him and have him check his end, because it's not returning a valid response. Otherwise your code really only needs some minor changes: http://jsfiddle.net/3J57y/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54953/discussion-between-dirty-bird-design-and-nbrooks).

Comment: Why don't you use $("#form").serialize(); instead of ConvertFormToJSON()